# SQL reset first_value for each "group" in dataset

Tags: sql, dataset, window-functions

I have the following dataset:

[image: Output]

I need to group the entries. (by date sorted and by column number 3 (419,440).

I tried the window_function first_value, to get the timestamp of the very first entry of each sorted group, but i struggle to figure out how to "reset" the function?

[image: Expected output]

Does someone knows how to figure this out, has an other idea how to "group" the dataset based on the columns above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want the most recent value where `col3` is different from the previous row.  If that is a correct interpretation, you can use:

```
select t.*,
       max(case when col3 = prev_col3 then null else col4 end) over (order by col4)
from (select t.*,
             lag(col3) over (order by col4) as prev_col3
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for your reply. 
I tried your solutotion, but it did not solve my problem.
I need somthing, (doesnt matter if its an date or not) where i can identify groups. The entries are created behind each other, but they do not have somthing like a "groupkey". So i need to create such a key. My approach was (col3 + newcol[date of first entrie of a group]) this should be unique so that i can keep working on.

Comment: @stefan . . . You don't really need a "group" identifier if you want the first timestamp when the value changes.  But the `max()` calculation can serve as a group identifier.